# Running into 'Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined' after installing packages

Tags: react-native

I run into the following error in ReactNative on app launch:

`Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined`

This usually happens after installing a new package or switching branches on my project with different sets of packages installed.

I'm can resolve it by running `react-native-git-upgrade` but this does not seem like a real solution.

Any ideas what can cause this error and how to avoid it?

Comment: Hey Christoph, any luck with that?

Comment: Nope, just random success by restarting packager, npm update and so on ... :(

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I managed to fix the issue after hours of dealing with this, and as you say just by following random suggestions. In my case I think it was some kind of npm cache and wrong version of React.

Answer (score 4):

was having the same issue and as you say, it's a version compatibility problem in react and react-native. Would also affect expo if you're using that.

**React + React-native have to use specific versions that work with each other.**

The [react-community org on Github provides a table](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md) that helped me install the correct versions. Here are a few examples from that document:

- react-native@0.41.x and 0.42.x need react@15.4.x
- react-native@0.43.x and 0.44.x need react@16.0.0-alpha.6
- react-native higher than 0.44 to 0.48 need react@16.0.0-alpha.12

Note that I did `npm install --save react@<correct version>`

Then `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

And lastly: `npm start --reset-cache`

My app runs again!

Answer (score 0):

It happens when your React-dom version is ahead of your React version and they are incompatible. Like the following will give this error as React-dom 16 is not compatible with React 15.

```
"react": "^15.6.2",
"react-dom": "^16.4.1",
```

Upgrade react or downgrade react-dom, basically use a compatible version of the both and that should fix the issue.